# New Raspberry PI 3 Won' Start

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2

I am new with Raspberry and just bought a new Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.
I've tried to follow from the internet a simple test.

So I did these:

1. Format 16GB mirco sd with SD formatter.
2. Download official Raspbian image.
3. Write the image to the micro sd with win32diskimager.
4. Put the micro sd to the raspberry micro sd slot.
5. Plug in HDMI to my monitor.
6. Plug in USB keyboard and mouse.
7. Use adaptor 5V 2A and plug to the usb power port.
8. Plug the adaptor to the power source.

And nothing happen. No led activity, no video output, nothing.
Some guy suggest that maybe the sd card is broken, or the adaptor is broken. I have replace the adaptor with 3 different adaptor, and reformat the micro sd and re-flash it. Still nothing.

I believe even the sd card is broken, at least the power led indicator should flashing. But there is no any led activity in the board.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic as this is not about programming. My Pi3's red power LED illuminates when it receives power, even with no SD card. If you have no power light, check your power source.

Comment: Thank you. Well I have used 3 different power adaptor and all are works fine with my smartphone. If your suggestion is correct that the power led should illuminate even without the micro sd, then the problem should be in the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the troubleshooting you have already done; it is safe to say that your Raspberry Pi is dead. The board should light the power LED even without the microSD card. If you already tested your USB cables, connectors and power supply and they all worked well with other devices; it's time to send the board back, get a refund and order a new one. Sorry mate, it sucks when that happens.

One last thing you may want to try, although, I would not recommend it unless you know what you are doing, is to power the RPi3 directly from the GPIO pins. You need to use 5V and connect directly to the 5V and GND pins. Be careful as powering the Pi this way you are bypassing the input current fuse. Meaning that you can easily fry the board with the smallest of short circuits.

Comment: Yeah... I really excited when the RPi3 is coming at my home. Before, I played with arduino and I am so curious with the powerful of RPi so I decided to try it. And yeah..it feel sucks when I just have my excitement but later found my first board is dead. I bought it online and it may take some few days to return and get a new one. Fortunately the seller give a replace warranty. I'll give an update.